# Unable to load non-js script after electron-builder build

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Context: Im developing an application using `electron`, with `electron-builder` to compile. All working in dev mode.

Structure:

```
|css
|--img
|----icon.ico
|--main.css
|js
|--preload.js
|--renderer.js
|--windows.vbs <- This is the guy I want to include
|index.html
|main.js
|package.json
```

package.json:

```
...
    "build": {
        "files": ["**/*", "*.vbs", "./js/*.vbs", "js/*.vbs"], <- Desesperate trying to make it work
        "win": {
            "icon": "./css/img/icon.ico",
            "asar": true,
            "requestedExecutionLevel" : "requireAdministrator",
            "target": ["portable"]
        },
        "portable": {
            "guid": "BD22D6EA-4798-4F59-9BB8-1BB916377BD6",
            "requestExecutionLevel": "admin",
            "artifactName": "File.${ext}"
        },
    }
...
```

**Issue**: Im running `electron-builder build` to create the exe and is working, creates the executable file in the `dist` folder as expected.

But when I run it (File.exe), throws an error `Can not find script file "C:\Program Files\MyApp\resources\app.asar\js\windows.vbs"`.

Not sure how to make this works, tried a lot of diferent suggested options but non of those are working.

*Note: if I run `electron-builder build` with setting asar in false (`"asar": false`) is working, so Im wondering if there somthing else around the "asar" property I can play with.

*Note2: `windows.vbs`is a simple script to create a shortcut in the desktop, my app basically download a zip file, un-compress it and creates a shortcut.